# How do I call a react router 4 redirect outside of the render function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am trying to navigate programmatically using RR4.  After I save some data, I then want to render a `Redirect` like this:

```
handleSave = () => {    
    this.props.mutate({
      ...
    });

    this.setState({
      org: null
    });

    <Redirect to="/orgs" />
    // return <Redirect to="/orgs" /> // Tried this also
};
```

I don't get an error, but the `Redirect` does not get rendered.  If I add a switch statement in my `render` function, then it will work:

```
render() {
    return ( this.state.rerender ? <Redirect to="/orgs" push /> :
        <View>
            ...
        </View>
        )
}
```

This works like I want it to, but I don't like the ternary statement.  Is there a way that I can add the `Redirect` to the save function, like I tried in my first example?

Comment: As i noticed you have push /> in your render function which you missed in handlesave function. And one more thing is - Did you check that your handleSave() function is calling or not.

Comment: `handleSave` is being called for sure.  I tried with/without push.

Answer (score 1):

use `history` `prop` and `push` or `replace` method. Every Route gets it, however you may also use `withRouter` HOC to inject it to other components.

Docs.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Comment: yeah, I'd definitely go with `withRouter` to do `this.prop.router.push`

Answer (score 1):

This answer has a lot of good information and examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121109/76672

Use withRouter.

This worked great for me:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```